# Javascript needs to be shorten

Tags: javascript

The code below is supposed to be a random color change  but I definitely did the long way in creating it. I also included the child function **Calculator**. I am willing to take suggestions as well if any of this can be made better. I tried to see if their could be a way to create this all in one line, but I had no luck. Also I tried to create a loop for the code but it was just too complicate for me. Can anyone help make the code less repetitive?

```
function calculator() {
    x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    return x;
}

function randomColor() {
    calculator();
    if (x == 1) {
        h.classList.remove("red");
        h.classList.remove("tan");
        h.classList.remove("green");
        h.classList.remove("light_blue");
        h.classList.remove("yellow");
        h.classList.remove("pink");
        h.classList.remove("purple");
        h.classList.remove("black");
        h.classList.remove("white");
        h.classList.add("sky");
    }
    else if (x == 2) {
        h.classList.remove("sky");
        h.classList.remove("tan");
        h.classList.remove("green");
        h.classList.remove("light_blue");
        h.classList.remove("yellow");
        h.classList.remove("pink");
        h.classList.remove("purple");
        h.classList.remove("black");
        h.classList.remove("white");
        h.classList.add("red");
    }
    else if (x == 3) {
        h.classList.remove("red");
        h.classList.remove("sky");
        h.classList.remove("green");
        h.classList.remove("light_blue");
        h.classList.remove("yellow");
        h.classList.remove("pink");
        h.classList.remove("purple");
        h.classList.remove("black");
        h.classList.remove("white");
        h.classList.add("tan");
    }
    else if (x == 4) {
        h.classList.remove("red");
        h.classList.remove("tan");
        h.classList.remove("sky");
        h.classList.remove("light_blue");
        h.classList.remove("yellow");
        h.classList.remove("pink");
        h.classList.remove("purple");
        h.classList.remove("black");
        h.classList.remove("white");
        h.classList.add("green");
    }
    else if (x == 5) {
        h.classList.remove("red");
        h.classList.remove("tan");
        h.classList.remove("green");
        h.classList.remove("sky");
        h.classList.remove("yellow");
        h.classList.remove("pink");
        h.classList.remove("purple");
        h.classList.remove("black");
        h.classList.remove("white");
        h.classList.add("light_blue");
    }
    else if (x == 6) {
        h.classList.remove("red");
        h.classList.remove("tan");
        h.classList.remove("green");
        h.classList.remove("light_blue");
        h.classList.remove("sky");
        h.classList.remove("pink");
        h.classList.remove("purple");
        h.classList.remove("black");
        h.classList.remove("white");
        h.classList.add("yellow");
    }
    else if (x == 7) {
        h.classList.remove("red");
        h.classList.remove("tan");
        h.classList.remove("green");
        h.classList.remove("light_blue");
        h.classList.remove("yellow");
        h.classList.remove("sky");
        h.classList.remove("purple");
        h.classList.remove("black");
        h.classList.remove("white");
        h.classList.add("pink");
    }
    else if (x == 8) {
        h.classList.remove("red");
        h.classList.remove("tan");
        h.classList.remove("green");
        h.classList.remove("light_blue");
        h.classList.remove("yellow");
        h.classList.remove("pink");
        h.classList.remove("sky");
        h.classList.remove("black");
        h.classList.remove("white");
        h.classList.add("purple");
    }
    else if (x == 9) {
        h.classList.remove("red");
        h.classList.remove("tan");
        h.classList.remove("green");
        h.classList.remove("light_blue");
        h.classList.remove("yellow");
        h.classList.remove("pink");
        h.classList.remove("purple");
        h.classList.remove("sky");
        h.classList.remove("white");
        h.classList.add("black");
    }
    else if (x == 10) {
        h.classList.remove("red");
        h.classList.remove("tan");
        h.classList.remove("green");
        h.classList.remove("light_blue");
        h.classList.remove("yellow");
        h.classList.remove("pink");
        h.classList.remove("purple");
        h.classList.remove("black");
        h.classList.remove("sky");
        h.classList.add("white");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `h`, `classList` and `x` stand for? Post a reproducible code that we can try in our browsers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array that maps numbers to colors. You can then loop over the array, either adding or removing the class as necessary.

```js
const colors = ["red", "tan", "green", "light_blue", "yellow", "pink", "purple", "black", "white", "sky"];

function calculate() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length));
}

function randomColor() {
  let x = calculate();
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    if (i == x) {
      h.classList.add(colors[i]);
    } else {
      h.classList.remove(colors[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Store your colors into Array
- When removing multiple `classList`s classes, from that array of colors, use the `spread` operator `...colors`
- Remember, you need to get a random from 0, not from 1 - since Array indeces are 0 based.

```js
const EL_btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const EL_div = document.querySelector("#div");

const colors = ["chartreuse", "coral", "chocolate", "crimson", "pink", "purple", "gold", "darkviolet", "deeppink"];  

const changeColor = () => {
  const rand = ~~(Math.random() * colors.length);
  EL_div.classList.remove(...colors); // Remove all
  EL_div.classList.add(colors[rand]); // Add one
}

EL_btn.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
changeColor(); // Init!
```

```css
.chartreuse { background:chartreuse; }
.coral      { background:coral; }
.chocolate  { background:chocolate; }
.crimson    { background:crimson; }
.pink       { background:pink; }
.purple     { background:purple; }
.gold       { background:gold; }
.darkviolet { background:darkviolet; }
.deeppink   { background:deeppink; }
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">CHANGE COLOR</button>
<div id="div">TEST</div>
```

If the array of colors is huge, spreading inside `classList.remove()` might be an expensive operation, than storing the current class inside a `data-color` attribute might leverage that process. Remove the class stored inside the `data-color` attribute and set a new random class:

```js
const EL_btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const EL_div = document.querySelector("#div");

const colors = ["chartreuse", "coral", "chocolate", "crimson", "pink", "purple", "gold", "darkviolet", "deeppink"];  

const changeColor = () => {
  const rand = ~~(Math.random() * colors.length);
  const color = colors[rand];
  EL_div.classList.remove(EL_div.dataset.color); // Remove remembered one
  EL_div.classList.add(color);                   // Add new one
  EL_div.dataset.color = color;                  // Remember new one for later
}

EL_btn.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
changeColor(); // Init!
```

```css
.chartreuse { background:chartreuse; }
.coral      { background:coral; }
.chocolate  { background:chocolate; }
.crimson    { background:crimson; }
.pink       { background:pink; }
.purple     { background:purple; }
.gold       { background:gold; }
.darkviolet { background:darkviolet; }
.deeppink   { background:deeppink; }
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">CHANGE COLOR</button>
<div id="div">TEST</div>
```